# Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.5 with systemctl - SELinux

Tags: permissions, rhel, selinux, postgresql

I've installed PG 9.5 (`/usr/pgsql-9.5/`) and when I start it manually with `postgres -D` it has no problems, but if I try to use `systemctl` I get an error. By looking to `journalctl -xen` output, I see:

```
/bin/sh /usr/postgresql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir: permission denied
```

These are the permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:postgresql_exec_t:s0 postgresql95-checkdb_dir
```

I cannot understand if it's a SELinux problem or something else. Any help?

Putting PostgreSQL in permissive mode (for example `semanage permissive -a postgresql_t`) solved the problem, but if I can, I want it to stay enforced. Do you know what kind of problem it is?

Comment: did you run -  /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb ?

Comment: Yes. If I run the check script manually it's all ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the wrong context (`postgresql_exec_t`). 
The solution:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "usr/pgsql-9.5/bin(/.*)?"
restorecon -vR /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin
```

Note the new context `bin_t`. I thought reading [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/postgresql_selinux) that `postgresql_exec_t was the correct context.